# printing and exporting Highcharts with logo

Tags: printing, highcharts, export

I want to add a logo when printing and exporting Highcharts only.
i tried with exporting and it works fine but with no hope with printing.
http://jsfiddle.net/andrew_safwat/zt5qLwe1/

```
    $(function () {
    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    if(this.options.chart.forExport) {
this.renderer.image('http://highsoft.com/images/media/Highsoft-Solutions-143px.png', 80, 40, 143, 57)
                    .add();
                    }


                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            animation: false,
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

any ideas please?

Comment: Use [beforePrint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.beforePrint) and [afterPrint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.afterPrint) events to add and remove logo from the chart.

Comment: thanks Pawel for your replay, but i don't know how to remove rendered logo in afterprint

Comment: In `beforePrint` store created logo: `this.myLogo = this.renderer.image(...).add();`. Then in `afterPrint` use: `if(this.myLogo) { this.myLogo = this.myLogo.destroy(); } ` to remove that logo.